# An issue in ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting

I am having an issue with getting a nice plot but `ListDensityPlot` is returning a plot with white area. I thought this could be due to the singularity, then I have also tried by manually removing the `ComlexInfinity` from the corresponding list, but the problem remains the same. `PlotRange --> All` doesnt seem to help either.

```
    x1 = 2;
    y1 = 2.45; a = 1;h = 1;l = 5;A = 0.5;alpha = 4;s = ArcTan[y1/x1]

    ListDensityPlot[Table[((((a^2*(l*h - alpha) + 
       s) - (a^2*x2 - a^2*y2 - 2*a*x2^2 - 2*a*y2^2)*
      A)/((x2^2 + y2^2)*(a^2 + (x1^2 + y1^2 + x2^2 + y2^2))))^2/4), {x2, -2, 2, 0.1}, {y2, -2, 2, 0.1}]]
```

Comment: `DensityPlot[((((a^2*(l*h - alpha) + 
          s) - (a^2*x2 - a^2*y2 - 2*a*x2^2 - 2*a*y2^2)*
         A)/((x2^2 + y2^2)*(a^2 + (x1^2 + y1^2 + x2^2 + y2^2))))^2/
   4), {x2, -2, 2}, {y2, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic]`. You can also change `DensityPlot` to `ContourPlot` to see contours.

Comment: `DensityPlot[
 Clip[((((a^2*(l*h - alpha) + 
           s) - (a^2*x2 - a^2*y2 - 2*a*x2^2 - 2*a*y2^2)*
          A)/((x2^2 + y2^2)*(a^2 + (x1^2 + y1^2 + x2^2 + y2^2))))^2/
    4), {0.001, 0.05}], {x2, -2, 2}, {y2, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotLegends -> Automatic]`

Comment: "the x and y labelling should be -2 to +2?" You need to tell `ListDensityPlot` it's from `-2` to `2` with `DataRange`. Currently this info is missing.

Comment: @Syed Thanks. Yes with `Clip` it is better than before but there's still some issue with it, dont know whether this can be entirely smoothed out.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks. I will add this to fix the range problem. However, the main issue is still the appearance of it.

Comment: "I have also tried by manually removing the ComlexInfinity from the corresponding list, but the problem remains the same. " How did you try? With `(*your data*) /. ComplexInfinity -> 10000` and `PlotRange -> All`, the white area goes away.

Comment: `there's still **some** issue with it` is not a scientific description. Mathematica does an accurate plot. If you don't like the color scheme, you an fake it with `Clip` etc.

Comment: @xzczd I replaced `ComplexInfinity` manually from the list, estimating it with a surrounding value of the elements before and after it. I changed it to `2300`

Comment: Then plotting that modified list again resulted in a similar plot with such regions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

x1 = 2; y1 = 245/100; a = 1; h = 1; l = 5;
A = 1/2; alpha = 4; s = ArcTan[y1/x1];

expr = ((((a^2*(l*h - alpha) + s) -
         (a^2*x2 - a^2*y2 - 2*a*x2^2 - 2*a*y2^2)*A)/
       ((x2^2 + y2^2)*(a^2 + (x1^2 + y1^2 + x2^2 + y2^2))))^2/4);
```

As the `PlotRange` is increased, the white area decreases

```
Manipulate[
 Column[
  {Plot3D[expr, {x2, -2, 2}, {y2, -2, 2},
    PlotPoints -> 100,
    MaxRecursion -> 3,
    PlotRange -> {0, max},
    ClippingStyle -> None],
   DensityPlot[expr, {x2, -2, 2}, {y2, -2, 2},
    PlotPoints -> 100,
    MaxRecursion -> 3,
    PlotLegends -> Automatic,
    PlotRange -> {0, max}]}],
 {{max, 1}, 0.25, 100, 0.25, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. The white area is however still there? Isn't there a way to circumvent it altogether? With increasing `PlotRange` the plot disappears entirely, i.e., `PlotRange-->All` leaves nothing to see in the plot.

Comment: @AtoZ I don't understand what your desired result would be. You see the shape of the 3D shape of your plot: what should happen in the density plot where the values go way up? Do you want a logarithmic representation of the density perhaps?

Comment: The center of the plot is unbounded and is clipped. The white area is the part of the plot that is clipped. You can use `ClippingStyle -> color` to change the white area to another color; however, that color will still represent that the region is clipped  (unknown values).